# Updating spreadsheet after altering the original one

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have the following data in spreadsheet A.

```
    name  trait1 trait2 nice
0   Adam  29     81     0
1   Barry 17     75     1
2   Chris 62     0      1
```

I wish to create a spreadsheet B that will be a filtered copy of this data. Namely, let's assume for a moment that I want to filter `nice = 1` and am interested only in column `name`. The copy in spreadsheet B would be as shown below. In spreadsheet B I wish to be adding some extra columns, e.g. `education`.

```
    name  nice education
1   Barry 1    primary
2   Chris 1    university
```

What I want to achieve is a spreadsheet B that will get updated if anything changes in spreadsheet A. So for example, if I were to change the name `Barry` to `Ben`. The spreadsheet B would become the following.

```
    name  nice education
1   Ben   1    primary
2   Chris 1    university
```

Similarly (and what I find to be the hardest), if a row is added in spreadsheet A, e.g.

```
    name  trait1 trait2 nice
0   Adam  29     81     0
1   Barry 17     75     1
2   Matt  69     11     1
3   Chris 62     0      1
```

The updated spreadsheet B would be as follows:

```
    name  nice education
1   Barry 1    primary
2   Matt  1    
3   Chris 1    university
```

So I want the education column to remain the same.

My approach of using a combination of `=IF()` and `=VLOOKUP()` functions ultimately did not work. Guess I am really curious about how to connect rows of education to names. So that when a row is added in spreadsheet A, then spreadsheet B gets updated but the education field connected to the new row is empty and will be filled by hand later on.

Comment: What version of Excel are you handling this data with? Things like actual tables and/or the use of the `FILTER()` function will definitely help.

Comment: Working on Excel 365 but wish to translate the solution to Google Sheets. Going to try out the `=FILTER()` function now!

Comment: So you want to use google sheets or Excel in the end? Both have `FILTER()` but GS also has `QUERY()`. Also, in your data, where does the 'education' data comes from?

Comment: The end product will be in GS, sorry for confusion.

Comment: So `=QUERY()` works for the first part of my question. When a row is added to spreadsheet A, then B gets updated but the education is not aligned anymore. Is there a way to repair that?

Comment: Well, where does the data come from? And how?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243784/discussion-between-bajun65537-and-jvdv).

Answer (score 3):

Since you are looking for a finished product to be in Google Sheets, I'd advise to use `QUERY()`:

[image]

Formula in `I1`:

```
=QUERY(INDEX({A:D,VLOOKUP(A:A,F:G,2,0)}),"Select Col1,Col4,Col5 where Col4=1")
```

---

**Note:** I made the assumption you pull the education in through a `VLOOKUP()` (since you mentioned that in the body of the question).

---

[image]

Comment: Just realized, very awesome way to accomplish it